# How to clear the Data Filter selection ? (CHOICE)

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I have three choice data filter's in the page. After selecting the value, I'm not able to clear it! (Is it a BUG ?) How can I clear that ? I'm using SharePoint 2013.

Comment: how you creating the filters and which webpart you are using? meanwhile check this blog, may be helpful
http://muzsharepoint2010.blogspot.com/2013/07/clearing-filter-selection-on-dataview.html

Comment: DataViewWebPart is used to show the list with filtered values.